# How to get a Mono QS param value in service call in Spring

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am quite new to Reactive so struggling a bit with the paradigm shift, but perhaps someone can help me get over this?

My controller passes a Mono (called "limit") to my service as a service param.  The Mono emits an Integer on subscribe that the service uses to do its work, which returns a Flux.

in my service method I need to subscribe to the mono - but I need to do that "before" my service method (which makes a web client REST call to some other endpoint) because the limit value is needed in the REST call. Now, I know that the subscribe will at some point complete, but it is completing after the main thread continues thru to complete the method.  My code:

```
public Flux<User> getUserdata(Mono<Integer> limit) {

        return
                Flux.from(WebClient.create()
                        .get()
                        .uri(uriBase, uri -> {
                            uri.queryParam("_limit", limit.subscribe(k -> String.valueOf(k)));
                        })
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToFlux(User.class));
}
```

If I hard code the limit param, this works. Someone I need to ensure that subscribe is completes.  I know I am still a bit mixed up with sync/async, so any ideas/advice on how to do this reactively/properly?

TIA,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

`Mono` and `Flux` are `Producers`. The one that is `subscribing` is called the `Consumer`. In your case, the final `Consumer` is probably the one that initiated the call. Most likely a webpage, or another service calling your service.

What im getting at is that since you are the `producer` most likely you should not call `subscribe` since you are not the final `consumer`. As soon as you see yourself doing this, you can tell this is a code smell.

I have rewritten your provided example below with some comments.

```
public Flux<User> getUserdata(Mono<Integer> limit) {

    // Should be created in a @Configuration annotated, as a 
    // @Bean WebClient is quite a large class and can affect performance.
    final WebClient webclient = WebClient.create();

    // We flatMap incoming mono to get the value, and then
    // call webClient, bodyToFlux returns a Flux for us.
    return limit.flatMap(l -> webClient.get()
                        .uri(uriBase, uri -> {
                            uri.queryParam("_limit", String.valueOf(l))
                               .build());
                        })
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToFlux(User.class));
}
```

Comment: Thanks!   that really helped...I am nearly there I think now, and your comments are very useful :  however I have to call build() on the uri :  return limit.flatMap(l -> webClient.get()
                .uri(uriBase, uri -> {
                     uri.queryParam("_limit", String.valueOf(l)).build(); 
                }) //missing return statement?
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(User.class));

Comment: I'd like to do this : but Intellij says there is a missing return statement :  return limit.flatMap(l -> {
            webClient.get()
                    .uri(uriBase, uri ->
                            uri.queryParam("_limit", String.valueOf(l)).build()
                    )
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(User.class);
        });

Comment: please dont write code in comments, and also, i dont have access to an idea so i wrote it from free hand. There is a missing return statement in the code you have written in the comment. `return limit.flatMap(l -> { ` you see the bracket, i didnt write a bracket.

Comment: yeah thanks again, I was trying a few things.   Appreciate your help....Now I have your example in the IDE, the compiler expects a ";" after the build() I am not finding the logic of what looks like a builder with a function in it easy to comprehend.

Comment: Then i suggest you google. Stack overflow is not a forum, its a Q&A site. This question has now been answered.